# WebRTC - help me understand a few concepts

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm new to WebRTC, actually just heard about it a few days ago and I've read a lot about it. However, I still have a few questions.

What do I need to explore the usage of WebRTC? E.g.: do I need a server, any libraries etc.? I'm aware that new version of Chrome and Firefox support WebRTC, but besides these two browsers, is there anything else that is necessary?

What is the main purpose of WebRTC when addressing practical usage? To video chat? Audio chat? What about text-chatting?

Does WebRTC need a server for any kind of browser-to-browser interaction? I've seen some libraries, such as PeerJS that don't explicitly mention any kind of server... so is it possible to connect two clients directly? There's also a PeerServer, which supposedly helps  broker connections between PeerJS clients. Can I use WebRTC without such a server?

What are the most commonly used libraries for WebRTC?

What's a good starting point for someone who's totally new in WebRTC? I'd like to setup a basic google-talk kind of service, to chat with one person.

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12739185/201952

Comment: You should look at http://www.webrtc.org/ . No special sever is needed as such and you can use native support of the browser but some wrapper would be needed to make it work across browser implementations

Comment: ["In the real world, WebRTC needs servers"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-real)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. However: "but some wrapper would be needed to make it work across browser implementations" what kind of wrappers are we talking about here?

Comment: there are good tutorials on practical uses of webRTC on youtube by New Circle Training (formerly Marakana tech tv). i highly recommend that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many docs [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/) E.g. [this one](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html), [this one](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html) and [this one](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-newbies.html)!

You can find a few libraries [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment#libraries).

A simple multi-user WebRTC app needs following things:

1. **Signalling server** to exchange sdp/ice/etc. ---- e.g. socket.io/websockets/xmpp/sip/XHR/etc.
2. **ICE server** i.e. STUN and/or TURN; to make sure Firewalls doesn't block UDP/TCP ports
3. **JavaScript app** to access/invoke RTCWeb JavaScript API i.e. [RTCPeerConnection](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-use-rtcpeerconnection-js-v1.1.html).

It just takes a few minutes to setup WebRTC peer-to-peer connection. You can setup peer-to-server connections as well where media-servers can be used to transcode/record/merge streams; or to relay to PSTN networks.

WebRTC [DataChannel](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/DataChannel#try-a-quick-demo-text-chat)s can be used for gaming, webpage synchronizing; fetching static contents, peer-to-peer or peer-to-server data transmission, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to explore the usage of WebRTC? E.g.: do I need a
>   server, any libraries etc.? I'm aware that new version of Chrome and
>   Firefox support WebRTC, but besides these two browsers, is there
>   anything else that is necessary?

WebRTC it is JavaScript API for web developers which can be used for audio and video streaming.

But there are 2 notices:

1. You need a signaling path.
   For example, if your first user is Alice using Firefox and second user is Bob using Chrome,
   they should negotiate used codecs and streams.
   WebRTC does not offer the signalling implementation. So you need to implement the signaling yourself. It is quite simple. You need to send SDP(stream config) to participant and receive an SDP answer. You can use plain HTTP via apahe server or use Websockets or any other transport to negotiate SDP.
   So, it seems you need an intermediary signaling server workning with websockets or HTTP/HTTPS.
2. Once you negotiated the streams you are sending your audio or video stream, but the distanation user might have a simmetric NAT. It means that you stream will not be delivered to the target user. In such situation you need a TURN server to traverse the NAT.

Finally you will need 2 server-side logic items:
1) Signaling server
2) TURN or proxy server

To start, take a look [Web Call Server](http://flashphoner.com/flashphoner-web-call-server-webrtc-rtmfp-sip-gateway/).
The server implements HTML5 Websocket signaling and SRTP proxying as a TURN server.
You can also [learn the webrtc application open source code](https://github.com/flashphoner/flashphoner_client/blob/wcs_video/client/client/src/js/rtc/WebRtcMediaManager.js).

First steps:
1. Download the signaling and streaming server.
2. Download and unzip web client.
3. Start the web client and debug javascript code to learn more how webrtc works.